# Activate selenium bot window in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to make the window of the selenium bot activated ...
First I declared this line

```
Dim mainWin As selenium.Window
```

then after the Get line

```
.Get "https://www.kuwaitcourts.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp"
```

I put this line that sets the window

```
Set mainWin = .Window
```

and before a message box I would like to activate the bot window so I used these lines

```
        mainWin.Activate

        MsgBox "Click OK After Entering Captcha", 64
```

There is no problem at the start of the loop as the bot window is already active but as for the second loop I didn't get the bot window activated
Any idea how to overcome this point and make the selenium bot window active when needed to be active

Thanks advanced for help

Comment: Have you tried using inputbox and setting the result to the appropriate element?

Comment: Thanks a lot.Can you give me more details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to return focus? For having window at front

```
bot.ExecuteScript "window.focus();"
```

---

Ways of pausing for input:

1. inputbox:

Why not use an inputBox (set to number type) to capture entry ? Below is pseudo code (assuming captcha is in an iframe which needs to be switched to.

```
Dim captchaBox As Object, captcha As Long
.SwitchToFrame (.FindElementById("someId")) '<==some identifier for iframe if present
Set captchaBox = .FindElementByCss("#txtCaptia")
' Accept Number from the user
captcha = Application.InputBox("Please enter 4 digit captcha:", "Captcha", , , , , , 1)
captchaBox.Value = captcha
'.SwitchToDefaultContent   ''<back to main if in iframe and is required even after submit.
```

---

2. `DoEvents` and loop until desired length:

Code

```
Dim submitButton As Object
Set submitButton =  .FindElementsByCss("#cmdSubmit")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until submitButtons.count = 0
```

Or

```
Dim captcha As Object
Set captcha =  .FindElementsByCss("#txtCaptcha")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until len(captcha.value) = 4
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196607/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-activate-selenium-bot-window-in-excel-vba).